# In ag-grid how to get dynamic header name?

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid with angular. I want one of the column name to be dynamic. So in colDefs object for that column I do not define headerName, rather define a headerValueGetter.

```
headerValueGetter: this.partnerHeaderValueGetter
'
partnerHeaderValueGetter(params) {

  return 'Select Partner';

}
```

I did not want it this way. There are two radio buttons, value of the dynamic header will depend on which of the radio buttons is selected. But parameter for the function partnerHeaderValueGetter is params which is having gridApi, columnApi etc.How to make this function aware of the radio button which is not part of ag-grid?
The code I wanted to work is as follows:

```
partnerHeaderValueGetter(params) {
  if (this.selectedSurveyLevel == 'Partner'){
    return 'Select Partners';
  }
  else if (this.selectedSurveyLevel == 'Site'){
    return 'Select Sites';
  }
  return 'Select Partners';
}
```

But the function partnerHeaderValueGetter cannot access 'this', it is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using arrow function instead. It's likely that you reference the wrong `this`.

- If you use the ES5 function (like in your question), `this` will be binded the the caller context.
- If you use the arrow function, `this` will be binded to the code that contains the arrow function.

```js
partnerHeaderValueGetter = (params) => {
  if (this.selectedSurveyLevel == 'Partner'){
    return 'Select Partners';
  }
  else if (this.selectedSurveyLevel == 'Site'){
    return 'Select Sites';
  }
  return 'Select Partners';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to use arrow function instead of normal functions:

```
someValueInComponent: string;
columnDef = [
    {
        headerValueGetter: (params) => this.someValueInComponent + ' some logic',
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, ur answer is correct & it obviously helped me. I can accept only one correct answer, so accepted the other answer for explaining in more detail.